# wp_insert_post allow to set taxonomy categories for non logged in users - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a button in the frontend and once clicked on it both logged-in and not logged in users left a message and I'm using wp_insert_post() function for adding new message, here is my code:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
    'post_type' => 'messages',
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $message,
    'post_excerpt' => $excerpt,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
    'tax_input' => array(
        'message-category' => array(26),
    )
));
```

But except adding new post, I need to set taxonomy category as well. But category is being set only when user is logged in. For not logged in users it is not working. I tried to add post_author (check above), but again that doesn't help.

Also tried to use below function, but again no luck and category is not being set when not logged in users left a message:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array(26), 'message-category', true );
```

And also tried with `post_category` but again no luck.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `post_category` as an argument of `wp_insert_post` function. Please refer to [doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/).

You function should look like this:

`

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
    'post_type' => 'messages',
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $message,
    'post_excerpt' => $excerpt,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
    'post_category' => array(6)
   )
);
 `
```

Comment: Notice that `post_category` is array parameter, Array of category names, slugs, or IDs.

Comment: Yes I know and did correspondingly. My code works fine when user is logged in but it is not working only when user isn't logged in @mokiSRB

Comment: Yeah it is really strange. I thought that post_author could help, but no luck @mokiSRB

Comment: you can try with `wp_set_post_categories`